# How to find all implementations of an interface with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Given I have a `InterfaceDeclarationSyntax` and the `SemanticModel`, is it possible for me to retrieve get all types that inherit the interface defined in `InterfaceDeclarationSyntax`? For example given `interface IFoo` I want to find things like `class Foo: IFoo` and `interface IBar: IFoo`, etc.

I've seen a SO question about how to find all implementations of an interface but they are not doing it programmatically, instead using ReSharper or tools in VS.

I'm trying to find a method that would match my needs through VS's intellisense and roslyn docs but not finding what I need. Hoping someone can shed some light.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call `SymbolFinder.FindImplementationsAsync(interfaceSymbol, solution)`.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.findsymbols.symbolfinder.findimplementationsasync)

Comment: prime example of why linking external sources is a terrible idea